# @azure/msal-angular 1.1.1 has TypeError: glob pattern string required

Tags: angular, azure-ad-msal

My Angular 8 has below error when running in `ng serve --aot` after upgrading to `@azure/msal-angular 1.1.1` and `msal 1.4.0` following the intruction at `https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-angular`.

```
TypeError: glob pattern string required
at new Minimatch (minimatch.js:116)
at azure-msal-angular.js:213
at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
at MsalService.push../node_modules/@azure/msal-angular/fesm5/azure-msal-angular.js.MsalService.getScopesForEndpoint (azure-msal-angular.js:212)
at MsalInterceptor.push../node_modules/@azure/msal-angular/fesm5/azure-msal-angular.js.MsalInterceptor.intercept (azure-msal-angular.js:367)
at HttpInterceptorHandler.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpInterceptorHandler.handle (http.js:1279)
at HttpXsrfInterceptor.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpXsrfInterceptor.intercept (http.js:1888)
at HttpInterceptorHandler.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpInterceptorHandler.handle (http.js:1279)
at HttpInterceptingHandler.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpInterceptingHandler.handle (http.js:1932)
at MergeMapSubscriber.project (http.js:1099)
```

it is working fine with `ng serve`

Any idea please?

Answer (score 0):

It is working if I create a Map of `protectedResourceMap`

```
const protectedResourceMap: [string, string[]][] = [
  [config.api, [environment.msScope]],
  ["https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me", ["user.read"]],
  ["https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me", ["user.read"]],
  ["https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users", ["directory.read.all"]],
  ["https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups", ["directory.read.all"]],
];
```

in

```
MsalModule.forRoot(
      {
        ...
        protectedResourceMap: new Map(protectedResourceMap),
      }
    ),
  ],
```

but MsalInterceptor fails to inject token into api calls.

Fixed: My cofig values are available after MsalModule is initialised so that Msal config is empty => glob error.